# How to define correct Service in NestJS according to .env?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

Sorry if the question may seem stupid but I guess such a realisation of code makes sense.
Let's say we have a common interface for the Users service.

```
export interface IUsersService {
getOne(id:string): UserType
getAll(): UserType[]
}
```

And we have 2 different realisations of UserService, let's say it would be

`CustomUserService`
and
`DefaultUserService`. These two services must satisfy the interface or implement it. Sorry for my English.

What if I want to make a logic which would choose one of those services according to .env constant. For example:

```
const userEnv = process.env.APP_USER
  ? process.env.APP_USER
  : 'default';
```

Then we should have something like Map or List to choose correct Service by the key
userEnv

```
const services: Record<string, UserInterface> = {
  default: { DefaultUserService },
  custom: {CustomUserService}
};
```

And after the correct building of such a logic we would be able to export service defined by
`.env`
to Controller or Module, whatever.
The logic I made above is incorrect and I Don't know how to make it with Services right. Do you have any suggestions regarding this? Please.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you like an abstraction of services with different implementations of the IUsersService interface.

It is possible to use Record to achieve this, so it's not a bad approach. You can set the key userEnv to a number or something similar and use the key to reference the service implementation in the Record using `myServiceMappings[userEnv]` and use the implementation of user service at that key.